# What's the procedure of decompressing one large file in remote servers?

Tags: filesystems, network-shares, file-transfer, nfs

I've mounted a net drive into my local computer and there are several large compressed files (e.g., ~100Gb) stored in this net drive. If I decompress the file using WinRAR, it seems the decompressing speed is very slow and I can also hear the busy sound for reading/writing my local disk. Then I doubt that if there are some huge data transfer from the remote server to my local computer. What's the detail in this procedure? Would the files in the large compressed file be first copied into my local disk, then copied back to the net drive in the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

#### Would the files in the large compressed file be first copied into my local disk?

It depends.

> then copied back to the net drive in the remote server?

It depends.

- If you use the `Extract...` option and select the destination though the WinRAR GUI, it will extract the files to the temporary directory and then move them afterwards.
- If you select the files you want to extract in the WinRAR window, Right click on them, choose `Extract to Specified Folder` it will extract without using the temp folder and copying.

You can also set the temp location using "Options" > "Settings" > tab "Paths".

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, thank you very much for your kind answer! But I think that is very incredible without copying the file into local computer. Does the net drive in remote server have a self memory to do this task for decompressing? That's amazing!

Comment: If winrar was started on your PC, and source (archived) file is on net disk, there will be (or was) transfer from net disk to your pc. If target file is on net disk, there will be transfer of unpacked data to remote server. (And with "Extract..." there will be temporary copy on your local disk.) Windows/Linux network shares in their protocol have no command "Do start archive program". Try some kind of remote access to the server to decompress data without network transfer of data - rdp, vnc, ssh, ... and start archive program at the remote server.